# Habilitar e Desabilitar Botão Salvar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Estou a desenvolver um sistema de lançamento de Receita/Despesa e esta funcionado de acordo com o que eu inicialmente preciso.

> **Processos.**
>   **Lançamento de Receita, adiciona o valor da Receita à tabela conta.**
>   Exemplo:
>   Saldo conta Inicial = 0,00
>   Lançamento Receita = 100,00
>   Saldo Conta = 100,00
>
> **Lançamento de Despesa, subtrai o valor da Receita à tabela conta.**
>   Exemplo:
>   Saldo Conta Inicial = 100,00
>   Lançamento Despesa = 50,00
>   Saldo Conta = 50,00
>
> **Estorno de Lançamento, subtrai ou soma de acordo com o tipo de lançamento(Receita ou Despesa) e valor adicionado.**
>   Exemplo:
>   Estorno de Receita
>   Saldo Inicial = 100,00
>   Estorno Receita = 100,00
>   Saldo Conta = 0,00
>
> Estorno de Despesa
>   Saldo Inicial = 100,00
>   Estorno Receita = 100,00
>   Saldo Conta = 200,00

O problema está quando clico em editar o lançamento, não altero nada no cadastro e salvo novamente. Só pelo fato de eu ter clicado em Salvar, O Calculo de atualizar o saldo é feito novamente, quando não deveria atualizar nada, já que não alterei nenhum checkbox.

Portanto, existe alguma forma de inabilitar o botão e habilitar somente quando de fato houver alguma alteração nos campos(Uma forma de validar entre os valores de antes e depois)?

Assim o botão **SALVAR ALTERAÇÕES** só estará disponível se a pessoa de fato alterar alguma coisa no modal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou, se houver alguma outra opção, seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: Este sistema é baseado no mapos? tenho bastante coisa que desenvolvi com base nele, podemos trocar algumas ideias.

Comment: @AndréBaill
Sim, também!
Vamos nos falando!!

Comment: Ok, qual seu contato? ou se quiser, me adicione no skype: srandrebaill :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando for editar:

```
$('form :input').change(function(){
   alert("Algum item no formulário foi alterado");
   //A partir daqui vocÊ pode habilitar o botão
   //Para desabilitar $('#idDoBotao').attr('disabled', true);
   //Para habilitar $('#idDoBotao').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou..
Ajuda até eu consegui desenvolver alguma coisa, vou utilizar seu código.

O ideal seria; sempre que eu voltar para o estado inicial(o mesmo estado de quando eu abri o modal) o botão voltasse para o estado disabled novamente.
Ou seja, permanecesse habilitado se realmente os valores fossem alterados, diferentes do que já está cadastrado.

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando a [resposta do @ggui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/158017/20615) como base, você pode salvar o valor do campo com o evento [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) e ao realizar a alteração pelo [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) ou qualquer outro evento que estiver utilizando, você realiza a verificação se o valor é igual ou não. Seria algo parecido com isso:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var valorOriginal;

  $('form :input').focus(function() {
    valorOriginal = $(this).val();
  }).change(function() {
    var novoValor = $(this).val();

    if (valorOriginal != novoValor) {
      $('#btn-salvar').attr('disabled', false)
    } else {
      $('#btn-salvar').attr('disabled', true)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <p>
      Descrição
    </p>
    <input type="text" value="Receita" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Fornecedor
    </p>
    <input type="text" value="Wagner" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Valor
    </p>
    <input type="text" value="250.00" />
  </div>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Salvar Alterações" id="btn-salvar" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Você também poderia utilizar o [.data-*](https://api.jquery.com/data/) para armazenar o valor antigo e realizar a verificação se o valor foi alterado ou não. Seria algo parecido com isso:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form :input').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('valor')) {
      $('#btn-salvar').attr('disabled', false)
    } else {
      $('#btn-salvar').attr('disabled', true)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <p>
      Descrição
    </p>
    <input type="text" value="Receita" data-valor="Receita" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Fornecedor
    </p>
    <input type="text" value="Wagner" data-valor="Wagner" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Valor
    </p>
    <input type="text" value="250.00" data-valor="250.00" />
  </div>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Salvar Alterações" id="btn-salvar" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Dessa segunda forma você tem a persistência do valor original o tempo todo, diferente da primeira forma.

Você também pode fazer de várias outras formas, como localStorage, cookies, hiddens, etc...

Todavia, validações no cliente pode não ser a melhor solução se não possuir a validação no server também. Então, acho melhor garantir a validação no server e depois pensar na validação no cliente.

Comment: Até tentei usar da forma que passou, mas não funcionou da forma que achei que funcionaria.
Poderia sim usar o cookies, localStorage. Mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: @WagnerFilho Qual das duas formas não funcionou conforme o esperado?

Comment: Fiz das duas formas.
A primeira carrega o botão com o atributo disabled = true. Se eu alterar algum campo, o botão passar a ser disabled = false(Até aí, tudo certo).
Mas se eu voltar o campo alterado para o valor de origem, o botão continua habilitado.
A segunda opção não funcionou.

Comment: @WagnerFilho Como eu disse na resposta, a primeira forma tem esse "problema". Já a segunda deveria funcionar. Se você clicar no botão "executar" em minha resposta, verá que está funcionando normalmente agora (esqueci de adicionar o jQuery anteriormente)

Comment: @WagnerFilho Devo informar que estou utilizando o evento `.change()`, então ele não verifica a cada tecla pressionada. Caso queira validar por tecla, altere o `change` para `keyup` que irá funcionar (nos inputs)

Comment: Bacana o teu exemplo, seria exatamente isso.
Só que ainda não tive a maldade para aplicar no meu código.

Veja como está o meu input: 
`<input class="span12" id="descricaoEditar" type="text" name="descricao"  />`

Enquanto o valor deste campo é atribuído pelo `$("#descricaoEditar").val($(this).attr('descricao'));`

Logo eu não sei como aplicar o `data-valor`.

Comment: @WagnerFilho `attr(descricao)` não existe. Se for seguir o exemplo você precisa criar o `data-descricao` e o valor deve ser recuperado com o `$("#descricaoEditar").val($(this).data('descricao'));` Algo desse tipo

Comment: Desculpe-me, teu código é incrível, mas não deu (Por falta de conhecimento mesmo).

Fiz assim:  `<input class="span12" id="descricaoEditar" type="text" name="descricao" data-descricao=""  />`

`$('form :input').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('descricao')) {
          $('#btn-salvar').attr('disabled', false)
        } else {
      $('#btn-salvar').attr('disabled', true)`

`$(document).on('click', '.editar', function(event) {
      $("#idEditar").val($(this).attr('idLancamento'));
      $("#descricaoEditar").val($(this).data('descricao'))`

Comment: Fiz somente com o campo descrição a fim de teste mesmo.

Mas muito obrigado pela força, já que aprendi algo mais...

Comment: @WagnerFilho Fiz uma alteração em seu código. [Veja se esse exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/fv5my2p9/) lhe ajuda a entender.

Comment: O meu problema, está em como recuperar do banco de dados o data-valor, da mesma forma que é recuperado em value.
Exemplo:
`value="valor recuperado"`
`data-valor="valor recuperado"`

Daí em frente, daria para fazer o que o código propõe.

Comment: @WagnerFilho Bom, aí já é assunto para outra pergunta. xD

Comment: te peguei né?! rsrs.
Obrigado pelo retorno.

De qualquer forma, agora tenho uma direção sobre o que eu queria...