# Recuperar do banco de dados o atributo "data-*valor" de um campo através do jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Como recuperar do banco de dados o atributo "data" de um campo através do jquery.

Hoje o sistema recupera o valor(value) do campo, mas agora preciso recuperar também o o valor data- deste mesmo campo, conforme pergunta [(clique aqui)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158010/habilitar-e-desabilitar-bot%C3%A3o-salvar/158017#158017).

A Finalidade deste, é fazer uma comparação entre o

> value  e .data-

Para que seja possível fazer uma condição para habilitar o botão salvar, caso algum campo do formulário seja alterado e inabilitar o botão se nada for alterado no formulário.

Segue como esta o campo em Html e Jquery:

```html
<label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
    <input class="span12" id="descricaoEditar" type="text" name="descricao"  />
    <input id="urlAtualEditar" type="hidden" name="urlAtual" value=""  />
```

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.editar', function(event) {
      $("#idEditar").val($(this).attr('idLancamento'));
      $("#descricaoEditar").val($(this).attr('descricao'));
      $("#descricaoEditar").val($(this).data('descricao'));
      $("#fornecedorEditar").val($(this).attr('cliente'));
      $("#valorEditar").val($(this).attr('valor'));
      $("#vencimentoEditar").val($(this).attr('vencimento'));
      $("#pagamentoEditar").val($(this).attr('pagamento'));
      $("#formaPgtoEditar").val($(this).attr('formaPgto'));
      $("#categoria_idEditar").val($(this).attr('categoria_id'));
      $("#conta_idEditar").val($(this).attr('conta_id'));
      $("#urlAtualEditar").val($(location).attr('href'));
      var estornado = $(this).attr('estornado');
      if(estornado == 1){
        $("#estornadoEditar").attr('checked', true);        
      }
      else{
        $("#estornadoEditar").attr('checked', false);
      }

      var baixado = $(this).attr('baixado');
      if(baixado == 1){
        $("#pagoEditar").attr('checked', true);
        $("#pagoEditar").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#estornadoEditar").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#divPagamentoEditar").show();
      }
      else{
        $("#pagoEditar").attr('checked', false); 
        $("#pagoEditar").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#estornadoEditar").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#divPagamentoEditar").hide();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que habilitar o botão com `"on change"` já seria suficiente, mas segue abaixo uma forma mais elaborada, em que se voltar o valor inicial do campo, o botão é desabilitado.

```js
$('form input').each(function() {
  $(this).data('value', $(this).val());
}).on('keyup', function() {
  $('button').prop('disabled', true);
  $('form input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('value')) $('button').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input value="valor1">
  <input value="valor2">
  <input value="valor3">
  <button disabled>Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para setar o valor `$('seuelemento').attr('data-valor', valorquevcker);`

Para ler o valor `$('seuelemento').attr('data-valor');`

---

Para pegar o valor do banco de dados em PHP e jogar na view no seu input ficaria algo +- assim:

`<input type="text" data-valor="<?php print $variavelcomovalordobanco ?>" />`

Talvez a forma de printar a variavel nao esteja certa, não sou bom em php, mas é algo dessa forma. Você vai ter que fazer o PHP printar o valor dentro do se input, pois o valor que vc ker vem do banco de dados

Comment: Renan,
E para ler o valor gravado no banco de dados?

Comment: @WagnerFilho para ler do banco de dados você vai ter que usar sua linguagem de backend (php, nodejs, c#, java, etc...). O jquery não faz isso, você vai expor esse dado do banco de dados com sua linguagem backend direto no elemento input

Se for PHP:
Na hora de renderizar o input, coloque o atributo data-valor="<?php $variavelcomovalordobanco ?>"

Após isso, pelo jquery vc vai conseguir pegar o dado

Coloquei na resposta como deve ficar o input em php

Answer (score -2):

Você pode pegar através de

```
var valor     = $("#estornadoEditar").val();
var descricao = $("#estornadoEditar").data("descricao");
```

Comment: Não deu certo.

O Atributo valor pega pelo `$("#descricaoEditar").val($(this).attr('descricao'));`

Este funciondo.
Gostaria de saber como atribuo este mesmo valor para data-campo.

`<input type="text" value="valor recuperado do banco" data-valor="valor recuperado do banco" />`

Comment: $("#descricaoEditar").data('valor', 'valor recuperado do banco');

Comment: E como eu posso pegar o valor gravado na coluna descricao, salvo no bando de dados?

Comment: Acho que sua pergunta não está clara, Wagner.
Pensei que sua dúvida estivesse em manipular o atributo data-valor, e não em buscar um valor no banco de dados.

Pode esclarecer qual sua real dúvida?

Comment: Então Vinicius, seria buscar no banco de dados o atributo data-*.
Eu sei como recuperar o valor, mas não sei atribuir este mesmo valor para data-*.