# Como Fazer com que um checkbox não seja selecionado se não houver seleção de outro anterior?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um pilha de mensalidades, onde cada uma se encontar em um select.

Gostaria que, a principio, todas elas estivessem desabilitadas excepto o primeiro check, e que ao habilitar o primeiro check, o segundo check pudesse estar disponível para ser habilitado, e se eu desabilitar o primeiro check, o segundo volta a estar indisponível (disable) para ser habilitado e assim por diante.

Ou seja só posso selecionar um checkbox se o chekbox anterior estiver selecionado

Gostaria de fazer isso co jquery ou php puro ou com outras sugestões.

```
<input type="checkbox" > Janeiro
<input type="checkbox" > Fevereiro
<input type="checkbox" > Março
<input type="checkbox" > Abril`
```

Comment: e qual a sua dúvida? pode colocar o código html e javascript do que já fez para podemos ajudar?

Comment: não seria nada semelhante a isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158010/habilitar-e-desabilitar-bot%C3%A3o-salvar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser feita uma função para quando clicar num *checkbox* verificar se o mesmo está marcado, se estiver habilita o próximo, caso contrário desabilita o próximo e desmarca também mesmo desabilitado.

Inicialmente é melhor deixar somente o primeiro habilitado no *HTML*.

```js
$(".meses").click(function(){
  let meses = document.querySelectorAll(".meses");
  for (let i = 0; i < meses.length; i++) {
    if (meses[i].checked && i+1 < meses.length){
      meses[i+1].removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
      if (i+1 < meses.length) {
        for (let j = i+1; j < meses.length; j++) {
          meses[j].checked = false;
          meses[j].setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="meses" value="1" type="checkbox">Janeiro
<input class="meses" value="2" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">Fevereiro
<input class="meses" value="3" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">Março
<input class="meses" value="4" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">Abril
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Caríssimo... Isso foi de grande ajuda....